# Cannot obtain Containing Assembly in Background Application

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I need to get the assembly for the application which is executing. In this case, it is a Background Application. Using reflection, I make the call:

```
Assembly test = Utilities.GetContainingAssembly(typeof(StartupTask));
```

During execution of that call, I receive an exception:
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

I am unable to find ANY references out there documenting the usage of this call....

Comment: What is your Utilitiies class look like? You may need to show us some more code.

Comment: @Jackie - this is a .net assembly include with IOT Core.

Comment: I know, how do you implement GetContainingAssembly?

Comment: ACK! I just discovered that this is part of a third party library. Insert face palm here. Thanks for helping me find that, @Jackie!

Comment: yeah, try if typeof(StartupTask).GetTypeInfo().Assembly works.

Comment: It does indeed appear to work. Now I will pass that to the third party code to see if it works. More to follow.

Comment: @Jackie - that did resolve the issue. If you want to put that into an answer, I will mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you implement Utilities.GetContainingAssembly(), but if you try the below method

typeof(StartupTask).GetTypeInfo().Assembly

It works with UWP app, and should work with BackgroundTask IoT project as well.